# AutoHotKey shortcuts stop working after a time

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts, autohotkey

I have a lot of text shortcuts in my .ahk file. These have worked well for me on all previous Windows platforms (XP, Windows 7) for me, and function correctly on Win 10 too.

*Except* after some unspecified amount of time, they just stop *working* across the board, in all applications.

Getting them going again requires me to right-click on the AutoHotKey icon in the tray and pick "Reload This Script". The shortcuts will then work again for a while.

This has happened to me on several different Windows 10 installations on different machines, so I don't think it's a local configuration issue.

Anybody know why this happens and (hopefully) what I can do about it?

Comment: Try to [debug the script](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Scripts.htm#debug) e.g. by displaying (MsgBox) what is happening at each shortcut, step or line.

Comment: How long is the "unspecified time", approximately? Minutes, hours, days, weeks? Do you restart your machine during that time? Do computer restarts affect the "lifespan" of your shortcuts? Can you provide your script file? Try compiling your script into an executable and see if this continues.

Comment: Could it be that one shortcut keeps "hanging" because it is not terminated properly and thus prevents the others from triggering?

Comment: I don't know exacly how long, It happens after some time during the day, after I've freshly rebooted the computer and AutoHotKey has started up.  At some point, I'd say within no more than an hour, I notice they've stopped working. I used to stop and restart AHK, but later noticed it worked just to reload the script from the tray icon context menu.

Comment: Yes. Somewhere the script might be hanging (wait infinitely for something.) If you post the script we might be able to point at where it is hanging. You can look at what the script is doing by right-clicking on the script tray icon->Open

Comment: Hello Thierry:

Thank you for the reply. It's been some time since I even thought about this. 

As time has gone on (and AutoHotKey has been updated a few times) this symptom occurs less and less frequently, I hardly notice it anymore.